# How can I set default value for option angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have select like this

```
<select  ng-model="form.data">
    <option  value="c" ng-repeat="c in data">{{c}}</option>     
</select>
```

```
$scope.data= response.data
```

When I change select and click save . It save successful in database . I want when refresh page . select show value I save in database. How can I do this . Please help me

Comment: did you checked my answer. i hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @RohitJindal yes , I still debugging my code . I will voteup later

Comment: @RohitJindal I try but I dont know it not work . Here is my plnkr . Can you see it http://plnkr.co/edit/FtPNwobT6NPyHwkvswMi?p=preview

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it is useful for you so that it will be helpful for others as well. I dont know who downvoted my answer

Comment: @RohitJindal problem is , I have a form with 10 field . And I use ajax to update all . I cant use localStorage and ng-change in this case

Comment: Then you can use `ng-submit` on submit button instead of `ng-change`. As per your question i provided my answer and it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some advice :**

- Use `ng-options` directive instead of traditional `option` element.
- To display the previous selected value on page refresh use `HTML5` `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/khd4xL93/)**

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be using the [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive:

```
<select ng-model="form.data" ng-options="c for c in data"></select>
```

This way, when refreshing your page the select will be default set to the value of `$scope.form.data`, as expected.

Comment: I dont know too. He downvoted all . I will upvoted later

Comment: Someone down voted all the answers on this question, probably having a bad day. I'm gonna up vote your answer.

Comment: Can you see it plnkr . Where is my wrong : http://plnkr.co/edit/FtPNwobT6NPyHwkvswMi?p=preview

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng As I said in my answer, you may use ng-options. [**Forked your plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhcjmjwidcJj2dIuQu22?p=preview). Note that in your controller, you didn't initialized formData: `$scope.formData = [];`

Comment: @Mistalis I see it , but can you check again ? When refresh page , nothing  value set

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng It is normal, the value is not stored anywhere. As you said, you get it/save it into a database. I don't see any $http call to a server/db here.

Comment: I try your demo , but I get `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng Because you didn't declare `$scope.formData` as an array. As I said, you have to declare it in your controller. Else, it problably comes from another part of your code (that you didn't provide).

Comment: yes I think you probably right . Here is old project of my company . And I cant use ng-options

Comment: @NguyễnBảoDũng I don't see why you could not use it. But it seems I can't help you more here... Try to play with the Plunker, you find any mistake in your project :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-selected`

```
<select ng-model="form.data">
  <option value="c" ng-repeat="c in data" ng-selected="c == form.data">{{c}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you see it plnkr . Where is my wrong http://plnkr.co/edit/FtPNwobT6NPyHwkvswMi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

## For people who are searching for a answer in Angular | angular 2 | angular 4

try using NgValue and make sure your default options value is the model so `NgValue="ModelName"`

```
    <select  ng-model="form.data">
      <option  NgValue="form.data">yourdefaultoption</option>
      <option  NgValue="c" ng-repeat="c in data">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Can you see it plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/FtPNwobT6NPyHwkvswMi?p=preview

Comment: The ng selected works indeed! My solution is for Angular not for AngularJS my bad